# Windows phone 8.1 Background Transfer request lost

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on Windows phone 8.1 application where i am using Background transfer API in the windows.networking namespace.

Here's what i am trying to do, while uploading multiple files to the sever using background transfer service, i lock the screen. The response to the upload request sent is lost.

Is there a way to store this information? Probably store it as an xml file and retrieve it later on when the app comes to the foreground ?

Comment: Have you looked at serializing (XML or JSON) the data to a file in LocalStorage?

Comment: How are you performing the uploads? i.e. show sample code that exemplifies the problem.

Comment: I am looking for ideas here. Also, i dont see a reason to place my code here. I am just using UploadOperation class from the Windows.Netowrking.BackgroundTransfer API.